# How do change the size of an image (not the size of the file, not the size of an image view) in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I scale down the size of an image in iOS using Swift? I don't mean make the file smaller as in less megabytes, and I don't mean reduce the size of the image view. I mean to actually alter the image to make it a smaller version of itself.

I have no code because I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Making a smaller image _will decrease the file size_. Do you mean that you don't want to compress it?

Comment: @Sweeper I don't want to decrease the file size, necessarily. I want to resize the image to a smaller scale so that it shows as a smaller image, so that when I place it in an image view, it looks smaller, regardless of how many megabytes are the files.